# Unexpected Java GZIPOutputStream results

Tags: java, gzip, gzipoutputstream

We have the following Java method to compress files using GZIPOutputStream

```
 private void archive(Path originalFile) {
    Path tempFile = originalFile.resolveSibling(originalFile.toFile().getName() + TEMPORARY_FILE_EXTENSION);
    Path gzippedFile = originalFile.resolveSibling(originalFile.toFile().getName() + ARCHIVED_FILE_EXTENSION);
    try {
        try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(originalFile.toFile());
            BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile.toFile())))) {
            IOUtils.copy(input,output);
            output.flush();
        }
        Files.move(tempFile, gzippedFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Files.delete(originalFile);
        LOGGER.info("Archived file {} to {}", originalFile, gzippedFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not archive file {}: " + e.getMessage(), originalFile, e);
    }
    try {
        Files.deleteIfExists(tempFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not delete temporary file {}: " + e.getMessage(), tempFile, e);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if we manually decompress back the file:

```
gzip -d file_name
```

**The resulting decompressed file does not match the original file.** 
The file size and the total number of lines are decreased. For example from 33MB to 32MB with a loss of 800K lines.

Could the issue be related with the encoding (**EBCDIC**) of the files we are compressing?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC

Comment: @JonSkeet Correct me if I’m wrong, but it appears the OutputStream is already part of the try-with-resources statement.

Comment: He's perfectly closing the streams.
Your problem must be on another layer as it seems. I tried your code and it performed flawlessly. Do you have enough space on the volume?

Comment: @VGR: You're absolutely right. I'd missed the location of the braces. (Obviously the scrolling doesn't help.) Will delete my first comment to reduce confusion.

Comment: @SirFartALot have created some Unit Tests and indeed I cannot reproduce the described issue. I will try to check if there were space issues when the error happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several Tests we have not been able to reproduce the issue, it must have been related with **not having enough space** on the volume during the compression. @SirFartALot thanks for pointing that out.